# show aggragated data in admin changelist_view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an app where I am tracking user searches. The table currently looks like this:

[image]

What I want to change is the view. I'd dlike to group/aggregate/annotate the view based on `Search Term` column and keep the latest date of each search term. The column `User searches` is being updated when user puts the same term in the search bar so there is no need for me to keep all records. I just need the latest one.

I tried to update queryset using `distinct()` and `annotate()` in admin model but with no success.

In other words I want to have 1 unique term in the table with the latest date (`Searched on` column).

Below is my code:

models.py

```
class SearchQueryTracker(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, unique=False)
    total_results = models.IntegerField('Search results', default=0)
    total_searches = models.IntegerField('User searches', default=0)
    search_term = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    searched_on = models.DateTimeField('searched on', default=timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def SearchViewFBV(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    query_list = request.GET.get('q', None).split()
    query_list_count = len(query_list)
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    find_duplicate_results = SearchQueryTracker.objects.filter(search_term=query).update(total_searches=F('total_searches') + 1)
    ....
    search_tracker = SearchQueryTracker()
    search_tracker.total_searches = find_duplicate_results
    search_tracker.author = user
    search_tracker.search_term = query
    search_tracker.save()
```

admin.py

```
class SearchQueryTrackerAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display  = ('search_term', 'author', 'total_results', 'total_searches', 'searched_on')
    readonly_fields = list_display
    list_display_links = ('search_term', )
    search_fields = ('search_term', )
    
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SearchQueryTrackerAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.order_by('-searched_on',).distinct('search_term') # not working
        # qs = qs.annotate(Count('searched_on')) # not working
        return qs
    
admin.site.register(SearchQueryTracker, SearchQueryTrackerAdmin)
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `SearchQueryTracker` each time on `SearchViewFBV`, you can use the `get_or_create` method to retrieve the `SearchQueryTracker` if it exists, or create it otherwise.

```py
@login_required
def SearchViewFBV(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    query_list = request.GET.get('q', None).split()
    query_list_count = len(query_list)
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    search_tracker, created = SearchQueryTracker.objects.get_or_create(
        search_term=query, author=user,
        defaults={'total_searches': 1}  # If it is created, assign the total_searches so you don't have to save afterwards
    )

    if not created:
        search_tracker.total_searches += 1
        search_tracker.save()
```

To avoid `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception you will need to clean your database of all duplicates first.